# How to get references of a standard field

Tags: standard-field, reference, where

I'm currently working on cleaning up the opportunity object and I'm facing an issue with getting the field references(Apex, Components, Workflow, Process Builder, Email templates, Reports) of complete org. I'm aware We can use the button named **'Where it is used'** on the field detail page.

But standard fields like(Stage name) don't have this option. how to handle this situation

Comment: Could you go into more detail about what you're hoping to do with this information? Standard fields can't really be edited all that much (and can't be removed).

Comment: We are trying to deactivate some of the existing values and going to add new values to the stage field, which will affect the existing references.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MetadataComponentDependency for "Standard" Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328124/how-to-query-metadatacomponentdependency-for-standard-field)

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to find out reports where the field being referred

Comment: For picklist values, it should be enough to write a query or a report filtered to particular values of interest to see where they are being used.

Comment: Hey sounds interesting could you please provide more details.

Comment: Have you tried metadata search apps on AppExchange?

Comment: Yes none of them have worked